# Utilizing tone.js NPM install on the client side

Tags: javascript, client-side, tone.js

I feel like I'm missing something totally obvious - but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use tone.js on the client. I see information on the website for how to install it server side via npm, but don't see a CDN or other link that I can reference to in a script src to pull the framework into a client-side project.

Is there something obvious I'm missing on the github page or elsewhere to reference/download so this can be used client side?

I saw some other posts on how to convert NPM packages into client side (e.g., browserify.js) but I feel like that's overkill...there should be just a simple way to use this in the browser.

documentation about it:

https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js

https://tonejs.github.io/

Comment: Like https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tone or https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/tone? It's a client-side library; installing it via npm means it's available for whatever web app packaging mechanism you're using (it can probably be built locally as well), and the [releases](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js/releases) includes the build artifact.

Comment: There is indeed: it's is just a JS library, and is loaded in the browser like any other: put the actual files from `node_modules/tone/build/esm` somewhere obvious relative to your html files, and then import tone.js into your own JS code using the modern esm syntax `import * as Tone from "the/tone/esm/dir/index.js"`. (Assuming you're not writing code that gets bundled for client-side use, because then you wouldn't run into this problem). Or alternatively, as already mentioned, use a CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not specific to Tone, but just use JSDelivr, which is a CDN that has every NPM package.

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tone@14.7

The NPM installation instructions are targetted at people already using front-end frameworks and are already using bundlers (basically everyone who isn't using jQuery or vanilla JS).

I would recommend against investing the time to learn Browserify. If you want to tinker with one, try something more modern like Webpack (more common) or ParcelJS (easy to use).